# How to generated unique id in ForEach with [Int]

Tags: swiftui

I am using a `ForEach` to construct a number of views based on an `array of integers`.
This `array of integers` can contain duplicate values. In addition, since an `Int` is not `Identifiable` I have to use a key path. When using `\.self` however, I get bad results (the colors of the rectangle are not correctly set)  due to the duplicate values.

What would be the easiest way to create unique identifiers or keypaths to fix this?

```
@ViewBuilder
func stackFor(bar: Bar, scale: CGFloat) -> some View {
    //sample data
    let values = [4,4,5,6]
    var index = 0
    //create stack of view
    //==> since an Int is not identifiable I have to use keypath
    //    however \.self is not unique as we have 2x the value 4 in the values
    //    this leads bad results because there are duplica ids
    ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
        Rectangle()
            .fill(colorForStackedBar(index: index))
            .frame(height: heightFor(value: value, scale: scale) )
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.clear)
            .frame(height: 1 )
        //the let _ = ... is just a "hack" for being able to update the index in @ViewBuilder
        let _ = index = index + 1
    }
}

func colorForStackedBar(index: Int) -> Color {
    return barColors[safeIndex: index] ?? .red
}

func heightFor(value: Int, scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let height = CGFloat(value) * scale
    //at least 1 point so to see __ on the bottom for zero (or missing) entries (as used on other apps)
    return max(1, height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by wrapping the `Int` into an `Unique:Identifiable` struct. However, I don't really think this is the most beautiful solution. There most be a better way?

```
struct Unique: Identifiable {
    let value: Int
    let id = UUID()
}

@ViewBuilder
func stackFor(bar: Bar, scale: CGFloat) -> some View {
    //sample data
    let values = [4,4,5,6]
    var index = 0
    //generate a uuid for the whole array of values
    let uniques = values.map({Unique(value: $0)})
    ForEach(uniques) { unique in
        Rectangle()
            .fill(colorForStackedBar(index: index))
            .frame(height: heightFor(value: unique.value, scale: scale) )
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.clear)
            .frame(height: 1 )
        //the let _ = ... is just a "hack" for being able to update the index in @ViewBuilder
        let _ = index = index + 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show more clear codes for **colorForStackedBar** or **heightFor** or **scale** and a screenshot of result of app what would be the result of this function?

Comment: Both functions are out of scope, they are not the cause of the issue. They just calculate the color and height of the rectangle based on the index (its part of a stacked bar chart).

Comment: But I do not know what you are trying solve whit this func which you cannot do with normal way?!

Comment: Please have a look at the the original question, the issue is that [Int] with duplicates cannot be used in a ForEach with a /.self because it can contain duplicate values.

Comment: But that is not an issue, let me show you an example

Answer (score 0):

Here array has duplicates but also works!

---

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        stackFor(scale: 1.0)
        
    }
}

func stackFor(scale: CGFloat) -> some View {
    
    let values: [Int] = [4 ,4 ,4 ,4 ,4 ,20, 20, 20, 50, 50, 50]
    
    return VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
        
        ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(colorForStackedBar(index: value))
                .frame(height: heightFor(value: value, scale: scale) )
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 5.0)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

---

```
func colorForStackedBar(index: Int) -> Color {
    return Color.red
}


func heightFor(value: Int, scale: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    
    return max(1.0, CGFloat(value)*scale)
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: I guess it depends on the actually drawing in the body/ForEacht, all I can say is that when I implemented my solutions my problem went away. They way SwiftUI is using the ids in the background is mysterious to me...

Comment: maybe printout the id:\.self in your loop. I bet you will see duplicates in there

Comment: I think your all codes need to be looked and controlled that is why I asked for more info at first place, I believe it is debugging issue not ForEach.

Comment: I hadded both functions to the org question, but as you can see they cannot influence the resulting view. I still believe its just an issue due to duplicate ids in swiftui and my approach did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Unique struct conform to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`:

```
struct Unique: Identifiable, ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    
    let value: Int
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

which makes it easier to create an array of Unique:

```
let uniques: [Unique] = [4,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Good idea and tip!